# how to call a variable in a public function from another function within the same class in php

Tags: php, class, oop

```
<?php  
class Pen  
{  
    public $color;  
    public function clr()  
    {  
        $this->color = "Red";  
    }  
    public function write()  
    {  
        echo $this->color; //if i write $ before color it gives me an error
    }  
}  
$a = new Pen();  
$a->write();  
?>
```

i tried to write an $ dollar in the write() function but it gives me an error
and in this code it shows nothing i even tried to use 
"class name :: function name ()-> color ;" didn't work either
i tried a lot of things that i found here but none of them really worked for me

Comment: You need to call `clr()` first, so `$this->color` is initialized, otherwise everything is correct. If you do: `$this->$color` it uses the value of `$color` as property name, but the variable doesn't exist here. Also add [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to get useful error messages and take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close ...

```
<?php  
class Pen  
{  
    public $color;  

    // Constructor, this is called when you do a new
    public function __construct($color = null)  
    {  
        // Call setColor to set the color
        $this->setColor($color);  
    } 

    // Method to set the color
    public function setColor($color) {
        $this->color = $color;
    } 

    // Write out the color
    public function write()  
    {  
        echo $this->color; 
    }  
}  

// Construct a new red pen
$a = new Pen('red');  

// Write with it
$a->write();  

// Change the color to blue
$a->setColor('blue');

// Write with it
$a->write();
?>
```

Take some time to read about PHP classes and objects at php.net.